# Determining a complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

I started learn complex numbers and solve complex numbers. I tried to do this example but I don't really know and don't understand how to do it.

I know that $z = a + bi$

 $a= \text{Re}$ and $b=\text{Im}$

Determine the complex number $$ if $_1= 2 + $ and is valid:
$$\text{Re}(\frac{z}{z_{1}})=-\frac{3}{5},$$
and

$$\text{Im} (\bar{z}z_{1}) = 1$$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: These conditions can be rewritten as giving the real and imaginary parts, and hence value as a complex number, of $z\bar{z}_1$; then you need only divide by $\bar{z}_1$.

Comment: Hint: if $z=a+ib$ then $\frac{1}{z}=\frac{a}{a^2+b^2}+i\frac{-b}{a^2+b^2}$ you can prove this multiplying $\frac{1}{z}*\frac{\bar{z}}{\bar{z}}$

and $z\bar{z}=a^2-b^2$

Use this to make a system of equations

Comment: Hint: you have $\,\text{Re}\left(\frac{z}{z_1}\right)=-\frac{3}{5}\,$ and $\,\text{Im}\left(\frac{z}{z_1}\right)=-\frac{1}{|z_1|^2}\,$ so you can easily find $\,\frac{z}{z_1}\,$.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways one could carry out the calculations to "extract" $ \ z \ $ from the given equations, as suggested in the comments above. A helpful identity for a beginner to know is that for $ \ z \ = \ a + bi \ \ , $ $ z·\overline{z} \ = \ |z|^2 \ = \ a^2 + b^2 \ \ . \ $  With  $ \ z_1 \ = \  2 + i \ \Rightarrow \  z_1·\overline{z_1} \ = \ |z_1|^2 \ = \ 2^2 + 1^2 \ = \ 5 \ \ , \    \mathfrak{Re} (\frac{z}{z_{1}}) \ = \ -\frac35 \ , \ \ $  and  $ \ \mathfrak{Im} (\bar{z}z_{1}) \ = \ 1 \ \ , $ it may be also helpful to get the same product of factors to appear in the expressions we are working with.  So we can take
$$ \frac{z}{z_1} \ · \ \frac{\overline{z_1}}{\overline{z_1}} \ \ = \ \ \frac{z \ · \ \overline{z_1}}{z_1\ · \ \overline{z_1}} \ \ = \ \ \frac{z \ · \ \overline{z_1}}{5} \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ \overline{\overline{z} \ · \ z_1} \ \ = \ \ z \ · \ \overline{z_1} \ \ . $$

We then have
$$  \mathfrak{Re} \left(\frac{z}{z_{1}} \right) \ \ = \ \ \mathfrak{Re} \left( \frac{z \ · \ \overline{z_1}}{5} \right) \ \  = \ -\frac35 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \mathfrak{Re} ( z \ · \ \overline{z_1}) \ \  = \ -3 \ \ \ , $$
$$ \mathfrak{Im} (\bar{z} \ · \ z_{1}) \ \ = \ \ 1 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \mathfrak{Im} (\overline{\overline{z} \ · \ z_1}) \ \ = \ \ -1 \ \ = \ \ \mathfrak{Im} (z \ · \ \overline{z_1}) \ \ .  $$

Thus, we have found that $ \ z \ · \ \overline{z_1} \ = \ -3 - i \ \ . \ $  Upon multiplying this equation through by $ \ z_1 \ \ , \ $ we obtain
$$ z \ · \ (\overline{z_1} · z_1) \ \ = \ \ (-3 \ - \ i) \ · \ z_1 \ \ = \ \ (-3 \ - \ i) \ · \ (2 \ + \ i) \ \  $$
$$ \Rightarrow  \ \ z \ · \ 5 \ \ = \ \ -6 \ - \ 3i \ - \ 2i \ - \ i^2 \ \ = \ \ (-6 + 1) + (-3 - 2)·i \ \ = \ \ -5 \ - \ 5i $$ $$ \Rightarrow \ \ \boxed{ \ z \ \ = \ \ -1 \ - \ i \ } \ \ . $$

[Computing $ \ \frac{z}{z_{1}} \ = \ \frac{-1 \ - \ i}{2 \ + \ i} \ = \ \frac{(-1 \ - \ i)·(2 \ - \ i)}{5} \ = \ \frac{-2 \ - \ 2i \ + \ i \ - \ 1}{5} \ = \ \boxed{ \ -\frac35 \ } - \frac15·i \ \ $ and $ \ \bar{z}·z_{1} \ = \ (-1  +  i)·(2 + i) \ = \ -2 \ - \ i \ + \ 2i \ - \ 1 \ = \ -3 \  + \ \boxed{ \ 1 \ } · i \ $ confirms that the specified conditions are satisfied.]